# Swift - Call self.navigationController into custom cell class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

Swift:

I have UICollectionViewController with another file/class UICollectionViewCell

The goal is to push `UIViewController` from my custom cell class.

something like this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I have no problems to implement push from `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` in `UICollectionViewController` but i want to do this from custom cell class registered into my `UICollectionViewController`.

When i try to push view from custom cell class unfortunately i don't have access `self.navigationController`

Also i want to do this 100% programmatically. I don't use Storyboard or Nib files

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a callback/closure from cell to view controller and invoke it in particular action of custom cell. So that on that callback you can perform push action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Views should not have/do that kind of logic. You should leave it with the Controller (that's what the [MVC-Pattern](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) is about).

Anyway:

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    var myViewController: MyViewController!
}
```

and when the cell is dequeued you could set it like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(myCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    let nvc: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    cell.myViewController = nvc.childViewControllers.first as! MyViewController

    return cell
}
```

and on selection:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    // I don't know where vc comes from
    cell.myViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Still, there is no case I can think of, where this would make any sense. So rethink your architecture again.

Visualize the communication of your entities, by drawing it on a paper. You'll have to draw **Models**, **Views** and **Controllers** and only **Controllers** are allowed to "talk" to other **Controllers**.

Look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/DefiningtheInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH7-SW1) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and advices. I will re-think my structure based on  MVC-Pattern. Vielen dank.

Comment: @ezcoding Why is this wrong? It immediately worked. For my situation I have a button inside the cell that needs to trigger the push. Because of the contents of the cell I can’t use the cell itself to push. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @LanceSamaria just because it works, doesn't mean it's the right thing to do. You should set up a delegate which informs the view controller, that displays the table view, about the button click.

Comment: It makes sense. That’s not hard to do. You should’ve included it in your answer but I can take care of that. Regardless you showed me something I didn’t know existed. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

I've recently came up with this question as well, and I have a way to  demonstrate Akhilrajtr comment, as it might help others as well.

First in your cell class you need a protocol in top of the file:

```
protocol YourCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol{
    func didPressCell(sender: Any)
}
```

Then in you cell class variables add this:

```
var delegate:YourCellDelegate!
```

When you are performing some action within your cell, trigger the function of your protocol:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    delegate.didPressCell(sender: indexPath)
}
```

On your super main controller, you should conform to the delegate you've created:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, YourCellDelegate{...}
```

And, implement the function of the protocol, which will be triggered when the cell is pressed, just like you defined it before:

```
func didPressCell(sender: Any){
    let vc = SomeViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Of course not to forget to give the reference for your delegate in the cell instantiation part in cellForItem function:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to extend on ezcoding answer. So instead of this code

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(myCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    let nvc: UINavigationController = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    cell.myViewController = nvc.childViewControllers.first as! MyViewController

    return cell
}
```

You can simply use `self` to get the current instance of the view controller, hence the code can be simplified to

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: MyCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(myCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.myViewController = self

    return cell
}
```

This worked for me at-least in my case.