# How can I use pushViewController inside a cell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a viewController where I have a tableview and inside every cell I have a collectionView.

I want to go to another view (where I will have a back button) so I tried to use my code which is working for the other views:

```
let vc =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detail") as! DetailView
    vc.name = beachesNames[indexPath.row]
    vc.imagak = imagesNames[indexPath.row]
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

But because this code is inside the TableViewCell I have an error that says:

> Value of type 'HomeViewCell' has no member 'storyboard'

Is there any alternative parameter that I can use or something else it could do my task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only UINavigationController can pushViewController. Only UIViewController should have UINavigationController. So, a way to do it is by using the delegate pattern, that will allow to tell the UIViewController which has at some point the cell (in general inside a UICollectionView, then a UICollectionViewCell) to push to VC with the target data to pass.

Comment: @Larme thanx for your comment can you give an example code ?

Comment: @Larme what I did is to set a `var del : HomeViewController?` and set it in my `cellForRow`  as  `cell.del = self` and then in my didselect (of collectioview) I just replace self with del. What do you thing about this is it good will I have a problem? (It works without any warnings)

Answer (score 2):

## - swift 3

```
let detailOrderVC = UIViewController()
self.viewController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailOrderVC, animated: true)
```

## - swift 4

> in swift 4, you need to pass the viewcontroller to the cell like below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // some your logic
    cell.viewController = self // CustomTableViewCell needs to have viewController member variable

    return cell
}
```

```
let detailOrderVC = UIViewController()
self.viewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailOrderVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: What will be "viewController()" in second line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing to a view class that requires layout you must call layout at the same time. 
ex.

```
 let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
 let nextViewclass = NextClass(collectionViewLayout: layout)
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewclass, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection view inside of every cell, then I would recommend having each cell hold a container view. The view controller associated with the container view will have a storyboard.

The code for the push would look a bit ugly:

```
self.parent?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The `parent?.` goes from the contained view controller to the parent view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I didn't quite understand you, what do you mean The view controller associated with the container view will have a storyboard. ?

Comment: @mikevorisis [Container Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html): [Here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/) is a basic tutorial from a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is instantiating the storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
```

But as this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31956931/swift-call-self-navigationcontroller-into-custom-cell-class) says, this generally isn't a good MVC design.

You might want to look into delegate patterns or using NotificationCenter. Both these ways essentially trigger a call to the parent view which will then handle the corresponding action.